# Dealing with Multiple Api Calls and Global Variables in Play Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to call 2 apis in a single method and I have to do a few calculations based on the responses I get.

This is so far what I have tried

```
def sortedRes() = Action.async {
    ws.url(url).get().map { response =>
      val value: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)
      val headVal = value.get.head
      ws.url(sortUrl).get().map { response =>
        val sorted: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)
        var sortedResult = sorted.get.head
      }
      println("----------------------")
      println(headVal)
      println(sortedResult)
      Ok(Json.toJson(sortedResult)
    }
  }
```

I am getting an error on `println(sortedResult)` line as it is not available there. How can I access `sortedResult` there in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `ws.url(whatever).get()` is asynchronous, it will return a `Future` that will contain your response, so it's not available in the moment you want to print it.

You have to `flatMap` the outer `Future` in order to manage the inner one, so then your `sortedResult` will be available

I think this is what you want to do:

```
def sortedRes() = Action.async {
  ws.url(url).get().flatMap { response =>
    val value: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)
    val headVal = value.get.head
    ws.url(sortUrl).get().map { response =>
      val sorted: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)
      val sortedResult = sorted.get.head

      println("----------------------")
      println(headVal)
      println(sortedResult)
      Ok(Json.toJson(sortedResult)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things about your written code:

1. **Use Flatmap on outer Future calls**: You have `asynchronous` action, every `ws` call type should have the `Future` type and therefore the outer `map` should be `flatMap` for avoiding dealing with `Future[Future[...]]`.
2. **Don't use var**: The whole point of functional programming is **immutability** use val instead. If you can' think about your architecture/design and re implement the written function.
3. **Move the action response to the body of Map**: For more clean approach, why not move the `Ok` response to the body of the second map?